# JQuery SVG - get the circle value of R

Tags: jquery, svg, geometry

I'm using [this SVG plugin](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html).

This is my code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#svgbasics').svg({onLoad: drawInitial});
});

function drawInitial(svg) {

    var mycircle = svg.circle(75, 75, '50', {fill: '#f2477b', stroke: 'none', 'stroke-width': 0, class_:'drag'});

    $('.drag').click(function() {
       $(this).animate({svgR: '0'},300, function() { $('.drag').css("display", "none"); });
    }

    $("#restore").click(function() {
       $('.drag').css("display", "block");
       $(this).animate({svgR: '50'},300, function() { });
    }
}
```

Generally, there is a circle of (radius) R=50 and when I click at circle it animate to R=0 and then disappears css("display", "none"). Then when I click to the #restore element it appears again with it's radius = 50. What I want to achieve is to get this '50' value from `mycircle` variable, something like: `svgR: $(this.R)`

How can I get this value from `mycircle` variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could only test this on Firefox, but in that browser `mycircle.r` returns an [SVGAnimatedLength](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/SVGAnimatedLength)  instance whose `animVal` property returns an [SVGLength](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/SVGLength) instance that, in turn, exposes a `value` property:

```
var radius = mycircle.r.animVal.value;
```

You can test it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2QfM/).

Note that using `animVal` rather than `baseVal` allows to get the current value of the circle's radius if it is being animated.